# Show the following limit doesn't exist $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}x\ln(xy)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}x\ln(xy)$$

I'm told to consider the line $y=e^\frac{-1}{x^2}$

So I did 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}x\ln\left(xe^\frac{-1}{x^2}\right) = \lim_{x\to 0}x\left(\ln(x)+ln\left(e^\frac{-1}{x^2}\right)\right) = \lim_{x\to 0}x\left(\ln(x)-\frac{1}{x^2}\right) = \lim_{x\to 0}x\ln(x)-\frac{1}{x}$$

And then I got stuck, as I don't know how to solve this limit.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that this is for positive $x$, as the expression doesn't make sense for negative $x$.

The final limit is easier than you might think. You have two terms: $x\ln(x)$ and $-\frac1x$. The first you know is negative (you might know that it goes to $0$, but that's not really relevant), while the second you know goes to $-\infty$ as $x\to 0$. Their sum clearly also goes to $-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{x \to 0+} x \ln (x)=\lim_{x \to 0+}  \frac {\ln (x)} {\frac 1 x} =\lim_{x \to 0+} \frac {\frac 1 x} {-\frac 1 {x^{2}}}$ by L'Hopital's Rule. Hence $\lim_{x \to 0+} x \ln (x)=0$. Rest is clear.